# OOP: centralized vs decentralized approach

Tags: object-oriented, client-server, procedural

Suppose you have a client-server architecture structured with a `Client` class that *asynchronously* implements the `Send()` and `Receive()` functions. 
You also have a base `Message` class and several other classes inherited from that class, based on the type of communication. This is the scenario:

1. When a message is received, the `Receive()` function creates the right istance of the class which inherits from `Message` class, which internally implements an `Handle()` function.
2. At the end of the `Handle()` function you need to send a message back using the `Send()` function of the `Client`.

To accomplish the point #2, which one of these two approaches represents the best-practice?

**Decentralized approach:**
call the `Client.Send(ReplyMessage)` function directly from the `Handle()` function in the `Message`. This means that all the `Message` classes can access and call the `Send()` function in the `Client`.

**Centralized approach**:
return the `ReplyMessage` to the `Client`, which will provide to call the `Send()` function internally.  In this way there is only one point where the messages are sent.

Comment: I don't see a "best practices" distinction here.  You would choose the approach that best implements your specific requirements.

Comment: Centralization encourages consistency; decentralization encourages flexibility. We can therefore make two contradictory arguments: centralization lowers costs because changes are consistently made in one place, and decentralization lowers costs because it enables changes to be made where they are needed. Without knowing what future changes you're going to need to make to your system, it is hard to know which to recommend! It is hard to make predictions, especially about the future!

Answer (score 1):

As written i.e. you *always* need to send a reply, then the centralised approach is probably slightly neater. I can see two potential benefits:

1. the common workflow (receive, handle, send) is all in one place;
2. the handle methods, the main locus of variability, may be easier to test independently from the architecture.

The first benefit is fairly minor given the simplicity of the workflow.

The second benefit will likely be most beneficial if you have a lot of message types with complex handling methods. If you only have a handful of message types and/or the handling is simple, there probably isn't much in the decision.

Answer (score 0):

> call the Client.Send(ReplyMessage) function directly from the Handle()

This goes against the principles of [loose coupling and separation of concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2832047), so what you called **centralized** approach is IMO a cleaner design:

```
Client.Receive(request)
response = message.Handle() 
Client.Send(response)
```

`message` is a `Message` attribute of `Client` whose concrete class (one of `Message`'s children) is determined dynamically depending on the type of `request`.